# Show a busy cursor spinner on the iPad?

Tags: ipad

How do I show/remove a busy cursor spinner on the iPad when doing a long operation?

Answer (score 3):

You use the [UIActivityView](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/346#post-1982) interface.